# Organize layout xamarin

Tags: xamarin, ffimageloading

I have the following command in my layout 
and I want to organize my layout so that the textview category stays on the FFImageLoading

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/L_imgF1F2">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/imgF1"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp">
                <FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
        android:id="@+id/imazhi"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#00000000" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CategoryF1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Category"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:gravity="left" />

              </LinearLayout>
```

I want my layout to be organized like this, 
As in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSa4U.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to use a `LinearLayout` here. The purpose of a `LinearLayout` is to stack `Views` one after the other. You should use a `RelativeLayout`, then on your `TextView`, set `android:layout_alignBottom="true"`, then set `android:layout_margin` to something appropriate to get it moved up and to the right a bit. Here's all of that together:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/L_imgF1F2">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imgF1"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp">
            <FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
    android:id="@+id/imazhi"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#00000000" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/CategoryF1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Category"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="left" />

          </RelativeLayout>
```